# Application of Trigonometry 2

Tags: trigonometry

My question is-
At the foot of a mountain the elevation of its summit is 45 degrees.After ascending one kilometer towards the mountain up an incline of 30 degrees,the elevation changes to 60 degrees.Find the height of the mountain.

I did not understand the question and I am unable to convert this question in the form of diagram.Any solution to solve this question would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
$AC$ is the elevation of your mountain, $ABC$ is your path. The elevation is $45 \deg$ , $AB$ is $60 \deg$ and $BC$ is $60 \deg$.

Comment: which angle is of 60 degrees?

Comment: the inclination of $BC$ with respect to horizontal is $60 \deg$ ... draw a plane passing through B

Comment: ok thanks a lot for explaining so well:)

Comment: my answer is (sq.root of 3 + 1)/2km am i right?

Comment: @meg_1997 check [this out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve++sin+30+%2B+y+sin+60+%3D+x%2C+z+sin+45+%3D+x%2C+z+cos+45+%3D+1+cos+30+%2B+y+cos+60) ,, x $x$ is height, $BC = y$, $AC = z$